# Writing to php://stderr

Tags: php, windows, xampp, stderr

I'm trying to get the use of php://stderr for writing logs to work. I'm using Slim framework which makes use of `@fopen('php://stderr', 'w')` for logging and really want this to work.

The following test cases should work but only the first one does:

```
// 1. error_log - works fine
error_log("Written through the error_log function", 0);

// 2. PHP wrapper, ie php://stderr - does not work
$stderr = fopen( 'php://stderr', 'w' );
fwrite($stderr, "Written through the PHP error stream" );
fclose($stderr);


// 3. PHP wrapper also, different syntax, just to be safe - no effect either
file_put_contents( "php://stderr","Hello World" );


// 4. PHP wrapper, this time using this elusive constant referred to in the manual - result: "Notice: Use of undefined constant STDERR - assumed 'STDERR' ", ie: failed also!
file_put_contents( STDERR, "Hello World" );
```

I've been looking through the PHP manual and Googling a lot but without much help.

In particular, the following quote from the PHP manual [on wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) is confusing:

> It is recommended that you simply use the constants STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR instead of manually opening streams using these [referring php://stdin, php://stdout and php://stderr] wrappers."

...given the undefined constant notice above. (I suspect those constants might be for use with PHP CLI -only?- but the page I'm citing does not state it.)

I've been wondering if this could be a Windows thing as I'm running XAMPP with PHP 5.3.8 for development but given the lack of topics on Google and the comments on PHP.net, I'm not so sure anymore. I do not have access to my production server logs right now for me to test out.

Comment: Oh thank goodness, I thought I was the only one that had the weirdly occasionally-undefined `STDERR` constant.  Where have you tested your example code?  What happens when you run it entirely by itself, through Apache?  It should show up in the *Apache* error log, right?  Does it not appear only when you're at the command prompt and/or going through that framework?

Comment: They are CLI only: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php

Comment: When I run the script, case 1 shows up OK, case 4. shows up in the log because of the missing constant only (this makes sense now given those are CLI-only). However, cases 2 and 3 are nowhere to be found.

Comment: (2) works perfectly in cli & apache here (don't forget to append PHP_EOL though), `file_put_contents` doesn't (not even with `FILE_APPEND`). That's with PHP as a module here, do you by any chance run it as (fast)cgi?

Comment: STDERR can also be used without being opened: fwrite(STDERR,"xxx");

Answer (score 16):

Never mind, got it. I did not quite get the difference between `php://stderr` and `error_log`:

`error_log` writes to the PHP error log (eg: D:\xampp\php\logs\php_error_log)

`php://stderr` writes to the server/Apache error log (eg: D:\xampp\apache\logs\error.log)

Hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: while I'm at it, in php://stderr, does stderr refer to the server's error log or to Apache's error log? (I understand they may be the same in practice but I'm curious as to the semantics.)

Comment: Technically, php://stderr refers to the STDERR stream for the process, but when running inside an Apache host as a module, this will be the STDERR of the Apache process.  If it is a CLI or CGI app, this will not be the case.

Comment: @richremer, My STDERR successfully writes to `C:\xampp\apache\logs\error.log`, but where does STDOUT get written to?

Comment: STDOUT gets sent to the client which made the request.  Whenever you echo, print, or use a template in PHP, it goes to STDOUT (ignoring any buffering).  It's the response for the request.

Answer (score 2):

If you are simply running PHP built-in web server (as of PHP 5.4.0) then `php://stderr` will be outputted to the screen of the console that launched PHP built-in web server.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot `file_put_contents` into STDERR; STDERR is a stream resource (already opened). So you can only `fwrite` to STDERR. Please see https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php