# Slim Framework - Warning: fopen('php:://stderr'), Invalid Argument Exception: Cannot create LogWriter

Tags: php, slim

I'm using Slim Framework for a web app. Everything was working fine but I wasn't able to use it today. The only 'usefull' error messages I'm getting are these:[image]

I don't know what could've gone wrong, I didn't make any changes since the last time I used it, that was a couple of days ago.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: we dont know what is wrong either (other than the error message) how about some code?

Comment: Might be some Windows/Permissions related problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13830285/writing-to-php-stderr

Comment: stderr doesn't exist on windows.